# how to restart the code so that it starts again from scratch?

Tags: python

the code receives some `inputs`, and I also have some `functions` to check the `inputs`, if they are wrong, I would like the program to restart so that it asks the user again to type correctly, however, without a `break`, the code continues to the next `input`

```
window1, window2 = infos_window(), None  # Using PySimpleGUI to create GUI

while True:

    window, events, values = sg.read_all_windows()

    if window == window1 and events == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if window == window2 and events == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break 

    if window == window1 and events == 'Continue':
        window1_values = values

        try:
            url_check(window1_values)
        except ValueError:
            break

        window1.hide()
        window2 = price_input()

    if window == window2 and events == 'Send':
        window2_values = values

        try:
            check_price(window2_values)
        except ValueError:
            break
```

Comment: Instead of break, I'd try `continue`

Comment: @BeRT2me but continue won't make the code move to the next window?

Comment: It'll start over the while loop, but I guess should do `window1, window2 = infos_window(), None` then `continue` to reset the windows to default?

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this not completely sure tho

```
main():
    while True:

        window, events, values = sg.read_all_windows()

        if window == window1 and events == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()
        if window == window2 and events == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            time.sleep(1)
            main()

        if window == window1 and events == 'Continue':
            window1_values = values

            try:
                url_check(window1_values)
            except ValueError:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()

            window1.hide()
            window2 = price_input()

        if window == window2 and events == 'Send':
            window2_values = values

            try:
                check_price(window2_values)
            except ValueError:
                time.sleep(1)
                main()
```

Comment: I just replaced the `break` for a `continue`, and that was enough

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary for multi-windows here, just call sub window in main window.

You can find that almost same code in both windows

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def sub_window():
    sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Value 2"), sg.Input("", do_not_clear=False, key="INPUT")],
        [sg.Button('Send'), sg.Button('Exit')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Title', layout, modal=True, finalize=True)
    window['INPUT'].set_focus()
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            value = None
            break
        elif event == 'Send':
            try:
                value = int(values["INPUT"])
            except ValueError:
                continue
            break
    window.close()
    return value

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Value 1"), sg.Input("", do_not_clear=False, key="INPUT")],
    [sg.Button('Continue'), sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Continue':
        try:
            value1 = int(values["INPUT"])
        except ValueError:
            continue
        value2 = sub_window()
        if value2 is not None:
            print(value1, value2)
window.close()
```

Comment: I just replaced the `break` with a `continue`, and that was enough

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the code inside a function and then use it whenever you want to restart everything. For example, I use main()

```
main():
    window1, window2 = infos_window(), None  # Using PySimpleGUI to create GUI

    while True:

        window, events, values = sg.read_all_windows()

        if window == window1 and events == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if window == window2 and events == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break 

        if window == window1 and events == 'Continue':
            window1_values = values

            try:
                url_check(window1_values)
            except ValueError:
                break

            window1.hide()
            window2 = price_input()

        if window == window2 and events == 'Send':
            window2_values = values

            try:
                check_price(window2_values)
            except ValueError:
                break
                
        main()
main()
```

Comment: I just replaced the `break` with a `continue`, and that was enough